# Creating a wallet on ether creates it on all EVN supported networks?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, blockchain, wallet, evm

When I create a wallet on Ethereum (f.e. with ether.js) -  I know the function that creates the keys is universal so it will create it for all Ethereum networks (Mainnet, Rinkbey, etc) but is the function universal for all EVM networks? will it also create it on Polygon Mainnet?

I couldn't find data about it so besides an answer I would be grateful if you could share a reference to read more about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases yes. For example the same private key derives to the same address on Ethereum, BSC, Polygon, Arbitrum, and many other EVM networks.

However, there are some EVM networks that use different address encoding. For example Tron uses a custom fork of EVM, and its addresses are in different format. So you might need to further encode the 20byte address to other chain-specific formats.